How to make Visual Studio evaluate Qt expressions?
Whatever Qt expression i try to evaluate while debugging on Visual Studio 2022 doesnt work, for example:


Conditional breakpoints with Qt expressions doesnt work.
Any Qt expression on watch window always: Function QWidget::height has no address, possibly due to compiler optimizations.

I'm on Debug mode, i also tried:
C/C++ > Optimization -> Optimization -> Disabled /Od
And also all options  here:

I'm using Qt 6.6, VS22 latest version available today.

Adding visualizer (natvis) might allow to see content of QT objects, limiting the need to call Qt functions in debugger.

@Jarod42 wdym? i'm using the Qt extension for VS

QT uses pimpl idiom, making debugger just shows raw pimpl pointer without visualizer or extension. With such visualizer, having w.height() in watch is less needed, as you might see directly (internal) informations from visualizer.

Not sure at which point debugger can show DLL code

Often inline functions are inline even in the Debug configuration.
Navigate to QtWidget::height() source to see
inline int QWidget::height() const
{ return data->crect.height(); }

Set a condition on w.data->crect.height().
If there's no success yet, repeat the condition expansion with crect.height() that will be like
w.data->crect.y2 - w.data->crect.y1 + 1.

What the problem with inline functions? w.data->crect can read the widget rect but what about objectName? Conditional breakpoints also doesnt work, i'm trying it wrong?
